# CSV to TSV converter in C+yacc+lex and a Makefile

Tags: c, csv, make, lex, yacc

This is Comma-Separated Values to [Tab-Separated Values](https://ftrv.se/1) converter written in C, with yacc(1) and lex(1).

I'm remembering how to use yacc (the first (and last) time I used it was while reading «The UNIX Programming Environment», but I have forgotten almost everything).

This code is based on an example from [begriff's blog](https://begriffs.com/posts/2021-11-28-practical-parsing.html#designing-against-an-rfc), with some modifications.

Yeah, I could do the whole conversion inside `csv.y` and use the main function from `-ly`. But I'm trying to remember how to communicate a structure pointer from a `.y` to a `.c` (and I think I'm doing that correctly).

csv.c:

```c
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "csv.h"

extern struct Record *records;

int yyparse(void);

/* call malloc checking for error */
void *
emalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p;

    if ((p = malloc(size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "malloc");
    return p;
}

/* call calloc checking for error */
void *
ecalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    void *p;

    if ((p = calloc(nmemb, size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "calloc");
    return p;
}

/* call strdup checking for error */
char *
estrdup(const char *s)
{
    char *t;

    if ((t = strdup(s)) == NULL)
        err(1, "strdup");
    return t;
}

static void
printfields(struct Field *fp)
{
    struct Field *next;
    char *s;

    if (fp == NULL)
        return;
    for (s = fp->str; *s != '\0'; s++) {
        switch(*s) {
        case '\t':
            printf("\\t");
            break;
        case '\n':
            printf("\\n");
            break;
        case '\\':
            printf("\\\\");
            break;
        default:
            printf("%c", *s);
            break;
        }
    }
    next = fp->next;
    free(fp->str);
    free(fp);
    if (next != NULL) {
        printf("\t");
        printfields(next);
    }
}

static void
printrecords(struct Record *rp)
{
    struct Record *next;

    if (rp == NULL)
        return;
    printfields(rp->fields);
    next = rp->next;
    free(rp);
    printf("\n");
    printrecords(next);
}

int
main(void)
{
    yyparse();
    printrecords(records);
    return 0;
}
```

csv.h:

```c
struct Record {
    struct Record *next;
    struct Field *fields;
};

struct Field {
    struct Field *next;
    char *str;
};

void *emalloc(size_t size);
void *ecalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
char *estrdup(const char *s);
```

csv.l:

```
%{
#include "csv.h"
#include "csv.tab.h"
%}

%option noinput nounput

%%

\"([^"]|\"\")*\" {
    size_t i, len;
    char *s;

    len = yyleng;
    s = yylval.str = calloc(len, 1);
    for (i = 1 /* skip s[0]='"' */; i < len-1; i++) {
        *s++ = yytext[i];
        if (yytext[i] == '"') {
            i++;    /* skip second one */
        }
    }
    return STR;
}

[^",\r\n]+ {
    yylval.str = estrdup(yytext);
    return STR;
}

\n|\r\n {
    return CRLF;
}

. {
    return *yytext;
}
```

csv.y:

```
%{
#include "csv.h"

struct Record *records;

int yylex(void);
int yyerror(const char *s);
%}

%union {
    struct Record *rlist;
    struct Field *flist;
    char *str;
}

%token CRLF
%token <str> STR
%type <str> field
%type <flist> record
%type <rlist> file

%%

start:
file {
    records = $1;
}

file:
record {
    struct Record *r;

    r = emalloc(sizeof(*r));
    *r = (struct Record){
        .next = NULL,
        .fields = $1,
    };
    $$ = r;
}
| record CRLF file {
    struct Record *r;

    r = emalloc(sizeof(*r));
    *r = (struct Record){
        .next = NULL,
        .fields = $1,
    };
    r->next = $3;
    $$ = r;
}
;

record:
field {
    struct Field *f;

    f = emalloc(sizeof(*f));
    *f = (struct Field){
        .next = NULL,
        .str = $1,
    };
    $$ = f;
}
| field ',' record {
    struct Field *f;

    f = emalloc(sizeof(*f));
    *f = (struct Field){
        .next = NULL,
        .str = $1,
    };
    f->next = $3;
    $$ = f;
}
;

field:
/* empty */ {
    $$ = ecalloc(1, 1);
}
| STR
;
```

Makefile:

```
PROG = csv
OBJS = csv.o csv.tab.o csv.lex.o
GENS = csv.tab.c csv.tab.h csv.lex.c
SRCS = csv.c csv.y csv.l

all: ${PROG}

${PROG}: ${OBJS}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${OBJS} -ly -ll ${LDFLAGS}

.c.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} -c $<

${OBJS}: csv.h

csv.tab.c csv.tab.h: csv.y
    ${YACC} -d -b csv csv.y

csv.lex.c: csv.l csv.tab.h
    ${LEX} -o$@ csv.l

tags: ${SRCS}
    ctags ${SRCS}

clean:
    rm -f ${OBJS} ${GENS} ${PROG} ${PROG:=.core} tags

.PHONY: all tags clean
```

Answer (score 5):

### Overview

### Code Review

Starting at the bottom and working up:

##### Lexer

This looks like it should work.
The only thing I would do differently is the `.` match at the end.

The only thing that this could legitimately match would be the comma. So I would make that explicit and then have `.` be an error condition.

```
,     {return ',';}
.     {/* Call error function as this is unexpected. */}
```

This is a very short lexer file, so I don't mind the way you have done it. But if it was for anything longer I would have set up named strings.

```
%{
#include "csv.h"
#include "csv.tab.h"
%}

%option noinput nounput

QuotedString            \"([^"]|\"\")*\"
UnQuotedString          [^",\r\n]+
EndOfLine               \n|\r\n

%%

{QuotedString}          {buildQuotedString();   return STR;}
{UnQuotedString}        {buildUnQuotedString(); return STR;}
{EndOfLine}             {return CRLF;}
,                       {return ',';}
.                       {error("Unknown Character");}

%%
```

---

I would note that a quoted string has to come immediately after a comma (or first character on line) and be terminated by a comma (or end of line). You may want to allow padding space that is ignored to allow your CSV file to be nicely formatted.

```
Padding                 [ \t]*
QuotedString            {Padding}\"([^"]|\"\")*\"{Padding}
```

On unquoted strings, leading and training white space is usually trimmed from the value (To have explicit white space in a cell you would usually quote it).

---

I have never seen a line like this in the parser file before:

```
 yylval.str = estrdup(yytext);
 ^^^^^^^^^^

 This part looks strange.
```

But it looks like it should work.

##### Parser

Again this looks good. But I tend to make my parser file one liners that call named functions.

```
%%

start:     file                {records = $1;}
file:      record              {$$ = makeRecord($1, NULL);}
    |      record CRLF file    {$$ = makeRecord($1, $3);}    
record:    field               {$$ = makeField($1, NULL);}
    |      field ',' record    {$$ = makeField($1, $3);}
field:     /* empty */         {$$ = ecalloc(1, 1);}
    |      STR                 {$$ = $1;}

%%
```

When I see lists in parser files they tend to be named `<X>List` but that is a bit overkill for something so simple.

Now that I have simplified, the one thing that stands out is that you can not have empty lists. i.e. You can not have a blank line with just `CRLF` on it. Now that is definitely something you could have done on purpose for a CSV file. But just in case:

```
 start:        fileList
 fileList:     /* Empty */
      |        file
 file:         recordList
      |        recordList CRLF file
 recordList:   /* Empty */
      |        record
 record:       field
      |        field ',' record
 field:        /* Empty */
      |        QUOTED_STRING
      |        UNQUOTED_STRING
```

##### C Code

I find putting the return type on the line above a bit strange:

```
void *
emalloc(size_t size)
void *
ecalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
char *
estrdup(const char *s)
static void
printfields(struct Field *fp)
static void
printrecords(struct Record *rp)
```

But this may be a C thing I have forgotten (I do mostly C++).

---

You use this `estrdup()` function just passing the `yytext` value.

```
estrdup(const char *s)
{
    char *t;

    if ((t = strdup(s)) == NULL)
        err(1, "strdup");
    return t;
}
```

I think this is a bug. The string pointed at by `yytext` is not guaranteed to be null terminated. Nor is the lexeme you just parsed null terminated. You need to use the `yyleng` value to get the length of the token.

```
getToken()
{
    char *t;

    if ((t = strndup(yytext, yyleng)) == NULL)
        err(1, "getToken");
    return t;
}
```

---

I don't like your comments.

```
/* call malloc checking for error */
```

I can see that very clearly from the code. So the comment becomes useless. Comment wrote in old code base is a real issue. So having useless comments is a bad thing. If you are going to have comments, explain WHY not HOW.

---

Sub statements (i.e. the statement after a `for`/`if`) prefer to always use code blocks. I have seen too many times a subtle error where a developer has indented two statements (expecting them both to be inside the if block) or some macro expansion that goes unnoticed.

```
    if ((p = malloc(size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "malloc");
```

It is never wrong to add a code block and it will probably save you one time in the future. So worth the extra line and couple of extra characters in typing:

```
    if ((p = malloc(size)) == NULL) {
        err(1, "malloc");
    }
```

---

I don't like the name of this function.

```
printfields(struct Field *fp)
```

It not only prints the fields but also frees up the list.

---

You use recursion in this function.
I think you would do better to use a `for()` loop. Though you are unlikely to hit a recursion limit, why take the risk?

```
printfields(struct Field *fp)
{
    struct Field *next;
    char *s;

    for (; fp; fp = next) {
        for (s = fp->str; *s != '\0'; s++) {
            switch(*s) {
                case '\t':
                    printf("\\t");
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    printf("\\n");
                    break;
                case '\\':
                    printf("\\\\");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("%c", *s);
                    break;
            }
        }
        next = fp->next;
        free(fp->str);
        free(fp);
        if (next != NULL) {
            printf("\t");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Same comments for this as above:

```
static void
printrecords(struct Record *rp)
{
    struct Record *next;

    for (; rp; rp = nexT) {
        printfields(rp->fields);
        next = rp->next;
        free(rp);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the unquoted string will match single characters that do include (among others)  either carriage return and newline characters but the end-of-line pattern matches with a single newline character or a pair of carriage return and newline characters. There is an edge case when there is a single carriage return character without a following newline character that appears to be unmatched (unless it is in a quoted string).

Answer (score 2):

### Makefile

The Makefile looks generally good.

We shouldn't need to write a `.c.o` rule - the built-in one is likely better.

I recommend adding some suitable warning/error flags to `CFLAGS`, certainly at least `-Wall` and likely also `-Wextra`.  We might need to disable some warnings when compiling the generated code, though - that's a good argument for minimising the C code in the yacc and lex input files - prefer to just call functions defined in other sources.

The `${PROG}: ${OBJS}` rule shouldn't need a command, provided we add `-ly -ll` to `LDLIBS`.  The built-in rule does better than this one, as it puts the `$(LDFLAGS)` expansion *before* `$(LDLIBS)`.

I'd probably use `$<` rather than spelling out the input filename in full in the lex and yacc rules.  Is there a good reason for not using the built-in rules here?

It's definitely worth familiarising yourself with the output of `make -f /dev/null --print-data-base` rather than reinventing wheels in your Makefile.